# Multiple insertion operator << in C++

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, insertion

I write a small code to see what happen if I use series insertion operators to own class.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class MyClass
{
    public:
        int i;
        MyClass & operator<< ( const string &  );

} ;

MyClass& MyClass::operator<< ( const string &  )
{
    cout << this << endl ;
}

int main()
{
    MyClass mc;

    mc << "hello" << "world" ;

}
```

It gives the result of two different memory addresses, which is beyond my imagination.

```
0x7fffdc69f6df
0x6020a0
```

I though it should be like:

```
(( mc << "hello" ) << "world" );
```

But in reality, it seems a "temporary" MyClass between the operations. This causes the member variable (for example, `int i` in the class) will not consistent. Can anyone give comments about this if I want the member variable (`int i`) can be access consistently.

Comment: Does this code even compile? The operator function doesn't return a value.

Comment: Looks like you have some serious misconceptions what `mc << "hello" << "world" ;` actually does. Your question makes no sense, everything works as expected.

Comment: Hello Matti! The code can be compiled.

I might not really understand the concept of the operator overloading. That's the reason I try to write small code to figure  is out. The code fail when I add i++ into the implementation

MyClass& MyClass::operator<< ( const string &  )
{
        i++;
        cout << this << " " << i <<  endl ;
}

Comment: @Chiat-ChhànÂng See my answer. [Clarify your question!](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably meant to write some code like follows

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyClass {
    public:
        int i;
        MyClass & operator<< ( const string &  );
} ;

MyClass& MyClass::operator<< ( const string & str) { // Note the parameter symbol
    cout << str << endl ; // Note usage of the parameter symbol "str", "this" is not 
                          // what you actually want here, it just outputs the address 
                          // of the class instance
    return *this; // Return the instance reference properly to allow chaining of
                  // subsequent operator<<() calls
}

int main() {
    MyClass mc;

    mc << "hello" << "world" ;
}
```

Output

```
hello
world
```

See [LIVE DEMO](http://ideone.com/dH1gDn)

---

Let's break this down:

```
 mc << "hello" << "world";
```

actually is the same as calling

```
 mc << "hello";
 mc << "world";
```

Returning the instance reference will enable the function being called in a *chain* of operator calls applied.

---

> *"But in reality, it seems a "temporary" MyClass between the operations."*

The problem occurs that you've been missing to return the current instance using the `return *this;` statement. Thus the accessing the expected return value results in undefined behavior for the 2nd call of the `operator<<()`. 
The compiler should have at least issued a warning about the missing `return` statement.